# Find volume bounded by inequalities

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of $K$ bounded by:
$0\leq z\leq 10-x^2-y^2 $, $x+1-y^2 \geq 0$ and $x+y^2-1 \leq 0$. I dont really understand how to go about this problem. What is the projection on the $xy$-plane?. My first idea was:
$$\iiint_K dzdydz = \iint_D ( \int_0^{10-x^2-y^2}dz)dxdy = \iint_D(10-x^2-y^2)dxdy.$$ But I don't understand what the domain $D$ is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.